# Kivy: send event and to parent and sibling widget

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am new in Kivy world. I want to pass the event and data to parent and sibling widget. I am not sure how I can do it.

Parent widget is screen manager and parent widget also have toolbar and I want to display total count of added items in toolbar. Add new item and view item are Screen widgets. On new item added I like to update the count in my parent widget toolbar and fetch the new data and load it in view screen.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome... What have you already tried?

Comment: Tried rxPy and push the event in Subject it worked but I am not sure how I can unsubscribe the observable in Widget. Also I have not seen people post on kivy with rxPy so I not sure whether it's good practice or not